# OpenMP offloading to Nvidia wrong reduction

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, openacc, offloading

I am interested in offloading work to the GPU with OpenMP.

The code below gives the correct value of `sum` on the CPU

```
//g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenmp
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)                                                                                                                                    
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) sum += i%11;
```

It also works on the GPU with OpenACC like this

```
//g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenacc   
#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:sum)                                                                                                                                    
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) sum += i%11;
```

`nvprof` shows that it runs on the GPU and it's also faster than OpenMP on the CPU.

However when I try to offload to the GPU with OpenMP like this

```
//g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) sum += i%11;
```

it gets the wrong result for `sum` (it just returns zero). `nvprof` seems to show that it runs on the GPU but it's much slower than OpenMP on the CPU.

**Why is the reduction failing with OpenMP on the GPU?**

Here is the full code I used to test this

```
#include <stdio.h>
//g++ -O3 -Wall acc2.cpp -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector                                                                                                                           
//sudo nvprof ./a.out                                                                                                                                                            
int main (void) {
  int sum = 0;
  //#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)                                                                                                                                    
  //#pragma acc parallel loop reduction(+:sum)                                                                                                                                   
  #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) {
    sum += i%11;
  }
  printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

Using GCC 7.2.0, Ubuntu 17.10, along with gcc-offload-nvptx

Comment: Probably sum is mapped to device as firstprivate (this is the default data-sharing attribute for scalar variables in target regions).

Comment: @IlyaVerbin, thanks, I got it to work by adding the clause `map(tofrom:sum)`. They don't to that in [these slides](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6510-jeff-larkin-targeting-gpus-openmp.pdf). I learned about it [here](https://www.exascaleproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/OpenMP-4.5-and-Beyond-SOLLVE-part-21.pdf).

Comment: yes, the default mapping changed between OpenMP 4.0 and OpenMP 4.5

Comment: @IlyaVerbin, do you have any idea why OpenMP is much slower than OpenACC for this operations on the same hardware?  OpenMP is about two times slower.

Comment: No, I don't have any experience with GPU programming. I would advise to compare the PTX code, which is generated for both cases. "gcc -foffload=-save-temps ..." should dump it.

Comment: @IlyaVerbin, the solution for the speed was to add the `simd` clause. Now OpenMP on the GPU is significantly faster than OpenACC or OpenMP on the CPU. See the end of my answer for more details.

Comment: why do you use `sudo` for running `nvprof` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add the clause `map(tofrom:sum)` like this:

```
//g++ -O3 -Wall foo.cpp -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum) map(tofrom:sum)
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) sum += i%11;
```

This gets the correct result for `sum` however the code is still much slower than with OpenACC or OpenMP without `target`.

**Update:** the solution to the speed was to add the `simd` clause. See the end of this answer for more information.

---

The solution above has a lot of clauses on one line. It can be broken up like this:

```
#pragma omp target data map(tofrom: sum)
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for(int i = 0 ; i < 2000000000; i++) sum += i%11;
```

---

Another option is to use `defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)`

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+:sum) defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)
```

Apparently, scalar variables in OpenMP 4.5 are `firstprivate` by default.
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/03/22/what-is-new-in-openmp-4-5-3/

`defaultmap(tofrom:scalar)` is convenient if you have multiple scalar values you want shared.

---

I also implemented the reduction manually to see if I could speed it up.  I have not managed to speed it up but here is the code anyway (there are other optimizations I have tried but none of them have helped).

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//g++ -O3 -Wall acc2.cpp -fopenmp -fno-stack-protector
//sudo nvprof ./a.out

static inline int foo(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a > b ? (a/c)*b + (a%c)*b/c : (b/c)*a + (b%c)*a/c;
}

int main (void) {
  int nteams = 0, nthreads = 0;

  #pragma omp target teams map(tofrom: nteams) map(tofrom:nthreads)
  {
    nteams = omp_get_num_teams();
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  int N = 2000000000;
  int sum = 0;

  #pragma omp declare target(foo)  

  #pragma omp target teams map(tofrom: sum)
  {
    int nteams = omp_get_num_teams();
    int iteam = omp_get_team_num();
    int start  = foo(iteam+0, N, nteams);
    int finish = foo(iteam+1, N, nteams);    
    int n2 = finish - start;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      int sum_team = 0;
      int ithread = omp_get_thread_num();
      int nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      int start2  = foo(ithread+0, n2, nthreads) + start;
      int finish2 = foo(ithread+1, n2, nthreads) + start;
      for(int i=start2; i<finish2; i++) sum_team += i%11;
      #pragma omp atomic
      sum += sum_team;
    }   
  }   

  printf("devices %d\n", omp_get_num_devices());
  printf("default device %d\n", omp_get_default_device());
  printf("device id %d\n", omp_get_initial_device());
  printf("nteams %d\n", nteams);
  printf("nthreads per team %d\n", nthreads);
  printf("total threads %d\n", nteams*nthreads);
  printf("sum %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

`nvprof` shows that most of the time is spend with `cuCtxSynchronize`. With OpenACC it's about half of that.

---

I finally managed to dramatically speed up the reduction. The solution was to add the `simd` clause

```
#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd reduction(+:sum) map(tofrom:sum).
```

That's nine clauses on one line. A slightly shorter solution is

```
#pragma omp target map(tofrom:sum)
#pragma omp teams distribute parallel for simd reduction(+:sum)
```

The times are

```
OMP_GPU    0.25 s
ACC        0.47 s
OMP_CPU    0.64 s
```

OpenMP on the GPU now is much faster than OpenACC and OpenMP on the CPU . I don't know if OpenACC can be sped up with with some additional clauses.

Hopefully, Ubuntu 18.04 fixes `gcc-offload-nvptx` so that it does not need `-fno-stack-protector`.

Comment: I got OpenACC to be about the same speed as OpenMP using `#pragma acc parallel num_gangs(128)` newline `#pragma acc loop gang, vector reduction(+:sum)`